# FixedPage Class and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, fixedpage

I have a FixedPage class as follows

```
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        double pageWidth = 96 * 8.5;
        double pageHeight = 96 * 11;
        fixedPage.Width = pageWidth;
        fixedPage.Height = pageHeight;
        Size sz = new Size(8.5 * 96, 11 * 96);
        fixedPage.Measure(sz);
        fixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), sz));
        fixedPage.UpdateLayout();

        ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
```

and an IEnumerable object as follows

```
IEnumerable<FixedPage> page;
page.Concat(new[] { fixedPage });
```

in the line

```
page.Concat(new[] { fixedPage });
```

Its showing error as

> *'Use of unassigned local variable 'page''*

How can I assign fixedPage to page?

I also need help to create a fixedPage object(elements)

Comment: When I try to run this code an InvalidOperationException (The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this) in PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();

Comment: I tried again by commenting the line PageContent pageContent = new PageContent(); Then same error in FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the page variable by creating a new instance of a class, which implements the **IEnumerable** interface, for example the generic **List** class:

```
IEnumerable<FixedPage> page = new List<FixedPage>(new FixedPage[] { fixedPage });
```

Comment: This is the answer for How can I assign fixedPage to page? I also need to get some insight on my deal with fixedPage class